# Getting Crystal Reports database logon after adding Ufl control

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report that is working fine in development and production, based off of a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012.

Everything works fine and dandy until I add a formula field that contains a custom Ufl function.

There is a single connection to the database and we populate it using the standard methods:

```
ConInfo.ServerName = .ServerName
ConInfo.DatabaseName = .DatabaseName

If .SQLCredentials.UseIntegratedSecurity = True Then
    ConInfo.IntegratedSecurity = True
Else
    ConInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False
    ConInfo.UserID = .SQLCredentials.SqlAuthUserName
    ConInfo.Password = .SQLCredentials.SqlAuthPassword
End If

LogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConInfo

For Each dbtable As Table In objReport.Database.Tables
    dbtable.ApplyLogOnInfo(LogonInfo)
Next
```

The server, database, user and password are all different in the production environment (and will be in all installed environments).

The UFL code I'm using accepts 3 strings (2 parameters and encrypted data) and returns the decrypted data (string)

```
Public Function Decrypt(ByVal cypherText As String, ByVal alg As String, ByVal keystr As String) As String Implements IEncryptionUfl.Decrypt
    Return decrypt(cypherText, alg, keystr)
End Function
```

If I have no fields in the report that use the UFL it works fine, but as soon as I include a Formula Field that includes the decrypt function it starts prompting for the login info on loading the report.

The database name field is ominously empty however...

Any ideas? Am I implementing the UFL incorrectly, or does Crystal handle the credentials differently when a UFL is used? I've updated to latest (SP17) CRforVS on the Dev PC and installed latest/matching runtime on the target.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL permissions of the UFL?  It appears they are different from those of the table you are using in the report.

Comment: Can you elaborate? The UFL doesn't touch the database directly and should just be passing strings around.